# How to remove Observer in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view in which I add the observer in `onAppear` and remove that observer in `onDisappear` method. But the observer does not get removed. I read the documentation but did not find any solution. Looking for help. thanks

```
struct MainListView: View {

       let NC = NotificationCenter.default
       var body: some View {
       VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
         .......
       }
       .onDisappear{
            self.NC.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "redrawCategories"), object: self)
        }
       .onAppear {
            self.NC.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "redrawCategories"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                .......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is SwiftUI approach to observe notifications

```
struct MainListView: View {

    let redrawCategoriesPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: 
          Notification.Name(rawValue: "redrawCategories"))

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
            Text("Demo")
        }
        .onReceive(redrawCategoriesPublisher) { notification in
            // do here what is needed
        }
    }
}
```